# Is there an alternative to RTLD_DEEPBIND flag in dlopen() function for platforms that don't support RTLD_DEEPBIND?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, cross-platform, posix, loading

I have the problem of a third-party library (say, TP.so) using an incorrect library version (say, GenericV1.so) instead of using the one that it is supposed to (say, GenericV2.so). The extra library is included for use in my program.

The straight-forward solution to this (well-documented on SO) is to use dlopen() with RTLD_DEEPBIND flag. But the flag is valid only on Linux, not other platforms like HP-UX, Solaris, AIX etc.

Is there an alternative for RTLD_DEEPBIND for use in these non-Linux platforms?

Thanks for your responses

Comment: I think the question should be "How to replace RTLD_DEEPBIND in a POSIX compatible way?" That will result in a platform independent implementation of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you do not really need RTLD_DEEPBIND at all. You only need to make sure the libraries with the competing symbols are loaded in the right order.

Some ideas:

1. You could use LD_PRELOAD to make sure the right library (GenericV2.so) is loaded before any other libraries.
2. You could make a function that dlopens the libraries in the right order: GenericV2.so and then TP.so.
3. Is it possible to make sure GenericV1.so is never loaded? Do you need anything from this library?